# How can I print out the attribute value instead of the element contents?

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I have an XML file like this:

```
     <wave waveID="1">
        <well wellID="1" wellName="A1">
          <oneDataSet>
            <rawData>0.1123975676</rawData>
          </oneDataSet>
        <well>
```

I am trying to print out the wellName attribute with the following code:

```
my @n1 = $xc->findnodes('//ns:wave[@waveID="1"]');  
  # so @n1 is an array of nodes with the waveID 1
  # Above you are searching from the root of the tree, 
  # for element wave, with attribute waveID set to 1.
foreach $nod1 (@n1) {  
  # $nod1 is the name of the iterator, 
  # which iterates through the array @n1 of node values.
my @wellNames = $nod1->getElementsByTagName('well');  #element inside the tree.
  # print out the wellNames :
foreach $well_name (@wellNames) {
   print $well_name->textContent;
   print "\n";
        }
```

but instead of printing out the wellName, I am printing out the rawData values (e.g. 0.1123975676).  I can't see why, can you?  I've tried to comment the code to help understand what is going on, but if the comments are incorrect then please correct me.   Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by 'raw rawData'? Do you mean like a reference, "SCALAR(0 × 814f5c4)"?

Comment: Thanks, I added more detail to the question.

Comment: You'll note that the XML contains a "rawData" tag. `textContent` prints out the textual content (not attributes) of this node and all child nodes - in other words, it would be expected to print `0.1123975676`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the `wellName` attribute of all `well` children of the particular `wave`, express that in XPath rather than looping by hand:

```
foreach my $n ($xc->findnodes(q<//ns:wave[@waveID='1']/ns:well/@wellName>)) {
    print $n->textContent, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$node->attributes()` returns a list of Attribute nodes.

The alternative is to fetch the attribute node directly with an XPath expression, rather than using XPath to go part of the way and manually doing the rest.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but it didn't work, are you able to help please?  

my @test = $nod1->attributes();      #should return a list of attribute nodes  

# now get the attribure  wellName from this list of attribute nodes
foreach $t (@test) {  

print $t->getAttribute(wellName);

Comment: Firstly, you want to call `attributes` on the node you want to get the attributes of. Secondly, there is no `getAttribute()` method in libxml - you need to iterate over the list of attributes and call `nodeName` to find the one you want.